# Submitting job to Globus Toolkit fails with SSL error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, debian-based, globus-toolkit

We are trying to get a basic Globus setup (*gram5* & *gsi* installed via Debian repo) working on a Ubuntu 13.10 system.
Additionally, we also try to setup the authentication via certs using the following commands:

#### Setup of SimpleCA

```
sudo grid-ca-create
sudo grid-default-ca
```

#### Create host cert

```
sudo grid-cert-request -host `hostname --fqdn`
sudo grid-ca-sign -in /etc/grid-security/hostcert_request.pem -out /etc/grid-security/hostcert.pem
```

#### Create user cert

```
grid-cert-request
sudo grid-ca-sign -in ~/.globus/usercert_request.pem -out /tmp/usercert.pem
cp /tmp/usercert.pem ~/.globus/usercert.pem
```

None of the above commands yields an error, so we assume, all is correct.

Then we try to run a test job via

```
globus-job-run localhost /bin/hostname
```

and it fails with:

```
GRAM Job submission failed because an authentication operation failed
OpenSSL Error: a_verify.c:221: in library: asn1 encoding routines, function ASN1_item_verify: EVP lib
OpenSSL Error: rsa_eay.c:721: in library: rsa routines, function RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT: padding check failed
OpenSSL Error: rsa_pk1.c:100: in library: rsa routines, function RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1: block type is not 01
(error code 7)
```

Is there any way we could debug or get to a more descriptive error message?
We already tried installing/setting up everything anew, with the same result.

Can anyone shed some light.

**EDIT:**

The following entry is written to `/var/log/globus-gatekeeper.log`:

```
TIME: Thu Oct 31 16:08:34 2013
 PID: 30238 -- Notice: 6: Got connection ::ffff:127.0.0.1 at Thu Oct 31 16:08:34 2013

Failed reading length 0
GSS authentication failure 
    globus_gss_assist token :3: read failure: Connection closed
Failure: GSS failed Major:01090000 Minor:00000000 Token:00000003

TIME: Thu Oct 31 16:08:34 2013
 PID: 30238 -- Failure: GSS failed Major:01090000 Minor:00000000 Token:00000003
```